# Distance from the closest non NA value in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe df and I want to add a column with the distance from the closest non NA value for each row.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:20)
df[c(1, 3, 4, 5, 11, 14, 15, 16), "x"] <-  NA
```

In other words, I am looking for the following values:

```
df$distance <- c(1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

How can I do this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `x` be your vector containing `NA`, your question is

```
a <- which(!is.na(x))
b <- which(is.na(x))
```

find `min(abs(a - b[i]))` for every `b[i]`.

This type of task is not easily to be accomplished **efficiently** with R code. Writing a loop with compiled code is generally a better choice; unless there is some function from some package that already does this for us.

Some naive but straightforward solutions are the following.

If `x` is not too long, we can use `outer`:

```
distance <- numeric(length(x))
distance[is.na(x)] <- apply(abs(outer(a, b, "-")), 2L, min)
```

If it is long and memory usage of `outer` becomes a problem, we might do

```
distance <- numeric(length(x))
distance[is.na(x)] <- sapply(b, function (bi) min(abs(bi - a)))
```

Note, none of the methods is truly efficient in view of the algorithm.

Comment: I have 20000 rows. It should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using `rle` and `rank`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(x=seq(1, 20))
df[c("1", "3", "4", "5", "11", "14", "15", "16"), 1] <-  NA

rle.len <- df$x %>% is.na %>% rle %$% lengths

df %>% 
  mutate(na.seq=rle.len %>% seq_along %>% rep(rle.len)) %>% 
  group_by(na.seq) %>%
  mutate(distance=ifelse(is.na(x), pmin(rank(na.seq, ties.method = "first"),
                                        rank(na.seq, ties.method = "last")), 0))

    x na.seq distance
1  NA      1        1
2   2      2        0
3  NA      3        1
4  NA      3        2
5  NA      3        1
```

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed your method will not work for the case of having a dataframe finishing with NAs in the last rows. It will consider the last row (which is NA) with a distance of 1 from a non NA value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findInterval`. First, find indices of `NA` and `non-NA` values, and initialize a distance column:

```
na <- which(is.na(df$x))
non_na <- which(!is.na(df$x))
df$distance2 <- 0
```

Then, use `findInterval` with midpoints of non-`NA` indices as breaks to find which interval `NA` indices fall in. Use the intervals to extract corresponding non-`NA` indices, calculate absolute difference to `NA` indices, and assign these at `NA` indices:

```
df$distance2[na] <- abs(na - non_na[findInterval(na, (non_na[-length(non_na)] + non_na[-1]) / 2) + 1])

df
#     x distance distance2
# 1  NA        1         1
# 2   2        0         0
# 3  NA        1         1
# 4  NA        2         2
# 5  NA        1         1
# 6   6        0         0
# 7   7        0         0
# 8   8        0         0
# 9   9        0         0
# 10 10        0         0
# 11 NA        1         1
# 12 12        0         0
# 13 13        0         0
# 14 NA        1         1
# 15 NA        2         2
# 16 NA        1         1
# 17 17        0         0
# 18 18        0         0
# 19 19        0         0
# 20 20        0         0
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use [`distance()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.8-19/topics/distance) in the [`raster`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.8-19) package, after using the package to convert your matrix into a RasterLayer object using the [`raster()` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.8-19/topics/raster).

The package is meant for maps so when you use `raster()`, your object will have units, resolution, etc. Thus when you use `distance()`, the distance may be very large for an element that is one away from a non-NA (15796.35 for me). Just divide by this amount (and maybe `round()` due to rounding errors) to get your answer.

As an example, if I have an array object with NAs called `a1`:

```
> a1 = array(
    c(
       c(1, 5, 6, NA, 1, 2, 5),
       c(3, 4, NA, NA, NA, 8, 1),
       c(5, 1, 7, NA, 2, 3, 7),
       c(8, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2)
     ),
    c(7, 4)
  )
> r1 = raster(a1)
> d1 = distance(r1)
> as.matrix(d1)    

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3] [,4]
[1,]     0.00     0.00     0.00    0
[2,]     0.00     0.00     0.00    0
[3,]     0.00 15796.35     0.00    0
[4,] 15796.33 31592.66 15796.33    0
[5,]     0.00 15796.33     0.00    0
[6,]     0.00     0.00     0.00    0
[7,]     0.00     0.00     0.00    0

> round(
     as.matrix(d1) / 15796.35,
     0
  )

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
[4,]    1    2    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0
[7,]    0    0    0    0
```

Which is your answer. I don't know how efficient the code behind the `distance()` function is, though, so I don't know if it will take a while or not.

EDIT: tested on an array object with 29000 NAs and it takes a long time. I advise you just use this for objects with few NAs.