# How to conditionally check and replace data in xts object?

Tags: r, for-loop, timestamp, time-series, xts

Here is a reproducible data set. The problem is to find 1 or 2 consecutive non-NA values in between a series of NA and assign them as NA. If there are more than 2, its fine nothing needs to be done.

```
set.seed(55)
data <- rnorm(10)
dates <- as.POSIXct("2019-03-18 10:30:00", tz = "CET") + 0:9*60

R <- xts(x = data, order.by = dates)
colnames(R) <- "R-factor"
R[c(1, 3, 6, 10)] <- NA
R
```

Output:

```
                        R-factor
2019-03-18 10:30:00           NA
2019-03-18 10:31:00 -1.812376850
2019-03-18 10:32:00           NA
2019-03-18 10:33:00 -1.119221005
2019-03-18 10:34:00  0.001908206
2019-03-18 10:35:00           NA
2019-03-18 10:36:00 -0.505343855
2019-03-18 10:37:00 -0.099234393
2019-03-18 10:38:00  0.305353199
2019-03-18 10:39:00           NA
```

Expected result:

```
                        R-factor
2019-03-18 10:30:00           NA
2019-03-18 10:31:00           NA
2019-03-18 10:32:00           NA
2019-03-18 10:33:00           NA
2019-03-18 10:34:00           NA
2019-03-18 10:35:00           NA
2019-03-18 10:36:00 -0.505343855
2019-03-18 10:37:00 -0.099234393
2019-03-18 10:38:00  0.305353199
2019-03-18 10:39:00           NA
```

I have written a function with for-loop which works fine for a small dataset but it's extremely slow. Original data consists of 100,000+ data points and this function couldn't execute it after more than 10 minutes

Can anyone kindly help me to avoid the loop to make it faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function `Fillin` which returns NA if the length is less than or equal to 3 (or 2 if the first element is not NA so that we can handle the first group even if it does not start with an NA) and returns its argument otherwise.   Use `cumsum` to group the runs and apply `Fillin` to each group.

```
Fillin <- function(x) if (length(x) <= 3 - !is.na(x[1])) NA else x
Rc <- coredata(R)
R[] <- ave(Rc, cumsum(is.na(Rc)), FUN = Fillin)
```

giving:

```
> R
                       R-factor
2019-03-18 10:30:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:31:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:32:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:33:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:34:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:35:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:36:00 -0.50534386
2019-03-18 10:37:00 -0.09923439
2019-03-18 10:38:00  0.30535320
2019-03-18 10:39:00          NA
```

### Performance

This solution runs at about the same speed as the one using `rle`.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  Fill = { Fillin <- function(x) if (length(x) <= 3 - !is.na(x[1])) NA else x
    Rc <- coredata(R)
    R[] <- ave(Rc, cumsum(is.na(Rc)), FUN = Fillin)
  },
  RLrep = { rleR <-  rle(c(is.na(R[,1]))) 
    is.na(R) <- with(rleR,  rep(lengths < 3 , lengths ) )
  }
)
```

giving:

```
Unit: microseconds
  expr   min    lq    mean median     uq    max neval cld
  Fill 490.9 509.5 626.550  527.7 596.45 3411.1   100   a
 RLrep 523.5 540.8 604.061  550.8 592.00 1244.4   100   a
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this based on [Distance from the closest non NA value in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465189/distance-from-the-closest-non-na-value-in-a-dataframe)

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(55)
x <- 100000
data <- rnorm(x)
dates <- as.POSIXct("2019-03-18 10:30:00", tz = "CET") + (seq_len(x))*60
time_table1 <- tibble(time = dates,data = data)
time_table <- time_table1 %>% 
  mutate(random = rnorm(x),
         new = if_else(random > data,NA_real_,data)) %>% 
  select(-data,-random) %>% 
  rename(data= new)



lengths_na <- time_table$data %>% is.na %>% rle  %>% pluck('lengths')

the_operation <- . %>% 
  mutate(lengths_na =lengths_na %>% seq_along %>% rep(lengths_na)) %>% 
  group_by(lengths_na) %>%
  add_tally() %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(replace_sequence = if_else(condition = n < 3,true = NA_real_,false = data))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(time_table %>% the_operation)
```

The results are quite good

```
Unit: milliseconds
                         expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 time_table %>% the_operation 141.9009 176.2988 203.3744 190.183 214.1691 412.3161   100
```

Maybe this is simpler to read

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(55)

# Create the data

x <- 100
data <- rnorm(x)
dates <- as.POSIXct("2019-03-18 10:30:00", tz = "CET") + (seq_len(x))*60
time_table1 <- tibble(time = dates,data = data)

# Fake some na's
time_table <- time_table1 %>% 
  mutate(random = rnorm(x),
         new = if_else(random > data,NA_real_,data)) %>%
  select(-data,-random) %>% 
  rename(data= new)


# The rle function counts the occurrences of the same value in a vector,
# We create a T/F vector using is.na function
# meaning that we can count the lenght of sequences with or without na's
lengths_na <- time_table$data %>% is.na %>% rle  %>% pluck('lengths')

# This operation here can be done outside of the df
new_col <- lengths_na %>%
  seq_along %>% # Counts to the size of this vector
  rep(lengths_na) # Reps the lengths of the sequences populating the vector

result <- time_table %>%
  mutate(new_col =new_col) %>% 
  group_by(new_col) %>% # Operates the logic on this group look into the tidyverse
  add_tally() %>% # Counts how many instance there are on each group 
  ungroup() %>% # Not actually needed but good manners
  mutate(replace_sequence = if_else(condition = n < 3,true = NA_real_,false = data))
```

Comment: @ Bruno, It works almost as per requirement. Almost because, it also replaces lone or couple NAs between a series of non-NA (which may not be a problem for me). 

As a beginner, it's a bit complex solution for me to comprehend but it actually worked very fast with the original large data set. So thank you for that

Comment: Hi @user11841472, You can make the if_else statement more complex to ignore the na's but I thought that this wouldn't change the end result, I will work on some comments, also if you are on rstudio abuse the f1 key to read about functions you don't know, maybe change you SO name? user11841472 feels impersonal

Comment: Keep getting `"Error in rename(., data = new) : unused argument (data = new)"`

Comment: I could replicate it in my existing workspace but restarting made it succeed. However it is not working on an xts object.

Comment: I converted my original data in xts to df with fortify.zoo() and it worked @42

Answer (score 1):

I guess, there are more elegant solutions around, but this cuts the time in half

```r
    R_df=as.data.frame(R)

    R_df$shift_1=c(R_df$`R-factor`[-1],NA) #shift value one up
    R_df$shift_2=c(NA,R_df$`R-factor`[-nrow(R_df)]) #shift value one down

# create new filtered variable
    R_df$`R-factor_new`=ifelse(is.na(R_df$`R-factor`),NA,
                               ifelse((!is.na(R_df$shift_1))|(!is.na(R_df$shift_2)),
                                      R_df$`R-factor`,NA)
```

```
>                 test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
>     2 ifelseapproach         1000    0.83    1.000      0.65     0.19         NA        NA
>     1       original         1000    1.81    2.181      1.76     0.01         NA        NA
```

Comment: Hi, this solution is only replacing the one non-NA but it's missing to replace the 2 consecutive non-NA values unfortunately.

Comment: Well, the function you posted in the original question before editing `removeErrorFun <- function(temp){
  for (i in 1:length(temp)-1){
    if (is.na(temp[i-1]$`R-factor`) && is.na(temp[i+1]$`R-factor`)){
      temp[i]$`R-factor` = NA
    }
  }
  return(temp)
}` left the two consecutive values in. So I seem to have misread your original post. You could easily expand my approach, but also by now you have other options ;-)

Comment: You are right, it was my mistake to put that function in the first place. I removed the function as soon as I realized. sorry for the inconvenience. @TobiO

Answer (score 1):

This is probably faster than most of the other solutions offered. The `rep` function is essentially the inverse of the `rle` function. It takes two vector arguments and expands the count of the values of the first by the lengths in the second and this allows a test based on the length of runs and then replacement with `is.na <-`. There are actually two different functions: rle(x) which returns a logical vector of length(x) and then there is `is.na(x)<-` which makes an assignment of NA to items in x depending on the logical values in the vector to the right of that function.:

```
rleR <- rle(c(is.na(R[,1]))) #get the position and lengths of nonNA's and NA's
is.na(R) <- with(rleR,  rep(lengths < 3 , lengths ) ) #set NAs
#--------------
> R
                       R-factor
2019-03-18 10:30:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:31:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:32:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:33:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:34:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:35:00          NA
2019-03-18 10:36:00 -0.50534386
2019-03-18 10:37:00 -0.09923439
2019-03-18 10:38:00  0.30535320
2019-03-18 10:39:00          NA
Warning message:
timezone of object (CET) is different than current timezone (). 


microbenchmark(
 Fill = {Fillin <- function(x) if (length(x) <= 3 - !is.na(x[1])) NA else x
ave(R, cumsum(is.na(R)), FUN = Fillin)}, 
 RLrep = {rleR <-  rle(c(is.na(R[,1])))
     is.na(R) <- with(rleR,  rep(lengths < 3 , lengths ) )})
#----------------------
Unit: microseconds
  expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
  Fill 1668.788 1784.6275 1942.5261 1844.5825 2005.0960 4911.762   100   b
 RLrep  102.174  113.9565  144.3477  131.4735  156.6715  368.665   100  a
```

Comment: I have slightly modified my code.  See the benchmark at the end of my post. They now run about the same speed with one having faster median time and other having faster mean time.

Comment: Well, I think "mine" seems more vectorized, but I'm pretty sure I learned this strategy from you many years ago on Rhelp, so I shouldn't  get too puffed up.

Comment: @42- This code works fine but I guess I am quite novice to fully comprehend your code. Just to learn what you did,  can you kindly elaborate this line? is.na(R) <- with(rleR,  rep(lengths < 3 , lengths ) ) .  Particularly I did not understand rep(lengths < 3 , lengths )  and using function on the both sides of the <-. Isn't is.na() for returning logical? If it is then how this line of code is assigning the lone values with NA? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to realize that `is.na<-` is actually a selective assignment function rather than being a composition of `is.na` and `<-`. See above edits.